# How to include only certain test packages in a maven test-jar & all non test code in a non test jar?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a maven module named `synapse`.

```
main
  java
    package1
      A.java

test
  java
    common
      C.java
    package1
      ATest.java
```

Can someone let me know if in maven I can create a non-executable jar containing all non-test code (`main/`) and another `test-jar` containing only the code under the package `test/java/common`?

I tried the below

```
<build>
  <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.0</version>
         <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>common/**</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I am observing that the `test-jar` is getting created as expected containing only the code from `test/java/common` but the non-executable, non-test jar does not contain the code from `main/java/package1`.

- Maven Version - 3.8.4
- Java 17

Comment: Why do you need a test-jar ? Why have you defined to skip the spring-maven-plugin? Why using an old Maven version?( Current version 3.9.6 https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration filter is being applied to the default jar as well as the test jar. Move your configuration into the scope of the execution:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>common/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: It is failing for a case. I have posted a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78236319/785523